# Is it dangerous to keep the CPU on 100% for several hours?

Tags: windows, intel, intel-core-i9

Currently I have a laptop with a 13th Gen Core i9 CPU.

Once per month I need to run a really heavy compilation that takes about 12 hours to complete. During this period, the CPU is usually stuck on 100% for hours and the machine's fan get really crazy and loud.

Is this dangerous to my machine? I mean, could it damage my machine?

Comment: No, it isn't. But you need to periodically clean the vents in order to have the best air flow at all times. And you may need to replace the thermal paste before you would if the usage was less intensive.

Comment: Agree.   Try to keep it at 99% .   Fan wear is inevitable over time.

Comment: Do you prop the laptop up on an object to facilitate airflow underneath? That might be a good mitigating action.

Comment: This has been asked repeatedly in the past. As long as your machine isn't permanently overheating with the CPU above 95 degrees C then you're probably fine.